# A jquery combine multiple .html set attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got some values gathered by ajax in this **data** like

```
$("#datset_egn").html(data['egn']);
$("#datset_tabnomer").html(data['tab_nomer']);
$("#datset_vhnomer").html(data['vh_nomer']);
$("#datset_podelenie").html(data['podelenie']);
$("#datset_email").html(data['email']);
```

etc. there are around 30 more and they are set together. Is there more elegant (easier and shorter) way to do this because I have to set the same amount of ids once again to blank if the ajax returns error ? Something like .. again:

```
$("#datset_egn").html('');
$("#datset_tabnomer").html('');
$("#datset_vhnomer").html('');
$("#datset_podelenie").html('');
$("#datset_email").html('');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set them all, you can use the keys as they match the ID's

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#datset_' + key.replace('_','')).html(value);
});
```

To reset them all, you can use the attributes starts with selector to select all elements where the ID starts with `datset_`

```
$('[id^="datset_"]').empty():
```

Comment: This is perfect! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a for loop that iterates through data values and sets the appropriate id.

```
for(var key in data){
    $('#dataset_'+key).html(data[key]);
}
```